# Symfony doctrine migrations problem

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, migration, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4.11 , I have a project...
I have schema.yml , and I have migrations with tables which are not in the schema. For example I have in my db "pages" table, and it not described in schema. When I get project in first time I make:  `build --all --and-load --no-confirmation` ; and I get my db,I think that it created some tables  from Base classes, because there are many tables in my db, but they are not described in schema . **So now** I need add a few new fields to my page table, I make migration, and it is all ok, I have new fields in my db, but I do not have it in schema.yml, so when I make `symfony doctrine:build --all-classes` nothing happen it do not generate page class with new column. I do not understand, if it possible to generate new class or changes to class without schema? How people that make project before me , do this?
Thank you!  And sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible. Try to use the following command to clean you model files.

./symfony doctrine:clean-model-files

if you want to use migrations, you should not use doctrine:build --all --and-load --no-confirmation anymore. Migrations assume incremental updates. Dropping and building the DB every time is not good.

Try to follow those resources

- http://www.slideshare.net/weaverryan/the-art-of-doctrine-migrations
- http://www.slideshare.net/denderello/symfony-live-2010-using-doctrine-migrations

Comment: Thank you! But when I make **./symfony doctrine:clean-model-files** it is delete all Base classes of the table which thare are no in my schema, and when I make build-classes it is do not generate new of table which are not in schema :(

Comment: The idea of ./symfony doctrine:clean-model-files is to remove the base classes of models that are not in your schema. It's a good thing right? I did not quite understand your point.

Comment: I need it base classes of models that are not in my schema:)After removing I can not generate it...

Comment: It's not possible what you're trying to do. The migrations cmd rely on schema yml and model classes comparison in order to determine what should be seen as db upgrade. Why would you want to keep the base classes that are not in schema?

Comment: I have project, and I have some modules which are generated on the model which are not in schema, now I need to modify some table, and it is not on the schema...

Comment: And why you just don't generate its schema? What's wrong with it being in the schema?

Comment: Yes, I create schema for those table..I thought that I can generate classes without schema, in some way)